# Data Protection using Entity Framework Core GenerateEmailConfirmAsync token is invalid when confirmemail

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

When user created from one domain and confirming from another domain , GenerateEmailConfirmAsync token is invalid when confirm email . I have used DataProtectionKeys for this but still token is coming as invalid.

My updated code in startup is

```
services.AddDataProtection().SetApplicationName("myidentityappname").PersistKeysToDbContext\<ApplicationDbContext\>();
```

ConfrimEmail

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> ConfirmEmail(string token, string email)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return View("Error");
            }           
            var result = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, token);
            return View(result.Succeeded ? nameof(ConfirmEmail) : "Error");
        }
```

Comment: tried with dataprotectionkeys filesystem as well. services.AddDataProtection()
    .SetApplicationName("myidentityappname")
    .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\\Users\\Downloads\\dataprotection")); 
File is creating but confirmemail is not working

Comment: From the description, seems you have used  IdentityServer 4 with Windows authentication together, then we could get the domain inforamtion. Please check it.